# How call method from another class?

Tags: java, android

i have 2 class, i put my method in first class

First.class

```
public void countIN (View view) {
    counter++;
    if (counter == 3){
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
}
```

and i want to call my method in my first class

Second.class

```
First myMethod = new First();
........
private void onClickButton(final ExpandableLayout expandableLayout) {
    expandableLayout.toggle();
    myMethod.countIN();
}
```

but its not work, i getting this error : StackTrace

```
Error:(85, 17) error: method countIN in class RecyclerViewActivity cannot be applied to given types;
required: View
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: Error seems to be clear, method `public void countIN (View view)` is declared to **require** as argument instance of `View`, but by calling it `myMethod.countIN()` you are not providing that instance. You need `myMethod.countIN(someViewInstance)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass null as parameter while invoking the method

```
myMethod.countIN(null);
```

but this is just for testing and for further actions you must either stop giving View view as a parameter in method:

```
public void countIN () {
counter++;
if (counter == 3){
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}
```

or use the parameter

```
public void countIN (View view) {
counter++;
if (counter == 3){
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        view.(do something)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You method
`countIN(View view)` require one(1) argument, which is a View type. However, you did not pass anything by calling it with 
`myMethod.countIN();`
either remove the argument in the method definition, (since you are not using it as far as I can see)
Or, you can provide the argument in the method call.

Comment: can you fix it ?

Comment: @DevonJoe Sorry but are you willing to put _any_ effort into your question? The error message told you what's wrong, now several people have told you what's wrong, but you're still too lazy to make the change? Your method requires a parameter but you're not calling it with one. If you don't understand that, take a Java tutorial.

Comment: i dont understand , can you help me to fix my code ? @bcsb1001